# How to properly reuse UIView in a mini game?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm creating a mini game where I need to reuse my UIView many times and I want to know how can I write my code properly.

I have an UIView which I need to create at first and later when user clicks on it must change its X position and disappear from the screen. Later in 3 seconds it needs to appear on screen again and etc.

So I need to reuse my UIView many many times. The question is how can I do it properly? Is it correct if I will create it, add as a subview and when it's gone from the screen to call removeFromSuperview? Or there are other way to reuse it and this way will the correct one?

And at the end as it's a mini game need I use SpriteKit or I need to create it with simple UIView.animateWithDuration?

Comment: Well even if it is a mini game i would recommend using SpriteKit.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a separate reference to the view it will not be released when you remove it from its superview.

```
lazy var actionView = UIView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    actionView.frame = ...
}
```

It sounds like you could also toggle the `hidden` property of the view when the user clicks on it.

Comment: so I need to save it and just relocate it when it disappears, yes?

Comment: yep just keep an instance variable in your ViewController.

Comment: and need I use for this matching game SpriteKit or something else? Or I can use simple animation? How it will be more professional?

Comment: That depends, is this view rectangular? Does it need to have some sort of collision detection? SpriteKit offers a lot in game building, it can provide extremely powerful tools. You'll have to weigh yourself whether or not those tools are needed for what you are trying to accomplish.